# php code to generate alternate no from for loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am generating book ,receipt ,coupon and price.

I used for loop to generate all the series.

Every forloop gets custom code and total value from textbox to generate all data.

Now my rerquirement is how to generate price in each coupon.

for ex- In below table ,Every receiptcode has 2 unique couponcode.Ok,

receipt    couponcode

701 =     501,502

702 =      503,504

703 =      505,506 OK.

**Now I need to also insert alternate price with each coupon like below example**

**for ex -**

couponcode       price

501            --    1

502            --    2

503            --    1

504            --    2

505            --    1

506            --    2

below is my code to generate all data using forlloop.

**plz suggest me how to generate alternate price with each couponcode.**

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['save']))
        {       
                    $city = $_POST['city'];                 
                    $scheme_name = $_POST['scheme_name'];
                    $amount = $_POST['amount'];

                    $bookcode = $_POST['bookcode'];             
                    $book_no2 = $_POST['book_no2']; 

                    $receiptcode = $_POST['receiptcode'];
                    $receipt_no = $_POST['receipt_no'];                     
                    $couponcode = $_POST['couponcode'];                         
                    $coupon = $_POST['coupon'];                         
                    $created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");             


                    $Temp_receipt = $receiptcode + $receipt_no;                 
                    $Temp_coupon = $couponcode + $coupon;

                    for($row1=$bookcode+1;$row1<=$bookcode+$book_no2;$row1++)
                        {   

                        for($row=$receiptcode+1;$row<=$Temp_receipt;$row++)
                            {

                                $query = $database->getRow("SELECT MAX(receipt_no) AS max1 FROM scheme_master;");
                                    if($query['max1']=='')
                                    {                           
                                        $largestNumber = $receiptcode;
                                        $top = $largestNumber + 1;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $largestNumber = $query['max1'];
                                        $top = $largestNumber + 1;  
                                    }       

                                    for($row2=$couponcode+1;$row2<=$Temp_coupon;$row2++)
                                    {                                   
                                        $query = $database->getRow("SELECT MAX(coupon) AS max2 FROM scheme_master;");
                                        if($query['max2']=='')
                                        {                           
                                            $largestcoupon = $couponcode;
                                            $coup = $largestcoupon + 1;                                 
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            $largestcoupon = $query['max2'];
                                            $coup = $largestcoupon + 1; 
                                        }   



  $insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO scheme_master (price,amount,scheme_name,city,book_no2,receipt_no,coupon,created)
VALUES (:price,:amount,:scheme_name,:city,:book_no2,:receipt_no,:coupon,:created)", 
array(':price'=>$pric,':amount'=>$amount,':scheme_name'=>$scheme_name,':city'=>$city,':receipt_no'=>$top,':book_no2'=>$row1,':coupon'=>$coup,':created'=>$created));

                                }

                        }
                    }
                        $_SESSION['message'] = "Books Created Successfully";                        
        }       

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to alternate between 1 and 2 in each iteration of your for-loop? That could be achieved like this:

First initialize `$loopCount = 0`

Then, in the loop, you do something like this:

```
if($loopCount++ % 2 == 0) {
    echo "1";
} else {
    echo "2";
}
```

Alternative:

```
echo $loopCount++ % 2 + 1;
```

It will check whether `$loopCount` will be even or uneven, and generate output accordingly.

That's how it works. It's up to you to integrate that in your code.

Comment: i think you are correct but plz tell me how to implement this in my code and insert every value in insert query....

Comment: Directly before the insert query, simply initialize e.g. `$couponPrice = $loopCount++ % 2 + 1;` and insert it in the correct database column. And initialize `$loopCount = 0;` before the for-loop starts. That's it.

Comment: i try this but this insert null value in price column..  below is my forloopcode   $loopCount = 0; 
        for($row2=$couponcode+1;$row2<=$Temp_coupon;$row2++)
        {   
             
         $query = $database->getRow("SELECT MAX(coupon) AS max2 FROM scheme_master;");
         if($query['max2']=='')
         {       
          $largestcoupon = $couponcode;
          $coup = $largestcoupon + 1;         
         }
         else
         {
          $largestcoupon = $query['max2'];
          $coup = $largestcoupon + 1; 
         } 
         $Pric = $loopCount++ % 2 + 1;

Comment: In your loop the variable is `$Pric`, in the insert query it is `$pric`. Capitalization.

Comment: exactly its working now....thanks for all your help but plz tell me one thing also...i need to make this count dynamic.... for ex  -  if my this loops runs 5 times then no $Pric = $loopCount++ % 2 + 1;   price value like 1,2,3,4,5,...if above loop runs only 3 times then $price insert 1,2,3, like wise...my mean is it alternates between 1 and loop times in each iteration . plz help me to do this i will accept your answer....after this...

Comment: for($row=$receiptcode+1;$row<=$Temp_receipt;$row++)
                            { }  this is my loop..

Comment: if this is not possible then tell me how to alternates this $Pric = $loopCount++ % 2 + 1; value from inputed values... for ex - if i input 1 and 5 then alternate between  1 & 5 in each iteration..

Comment: And I answered your question already. So requiring me to keep helping you with more and more problems just so you accept my answer is very rude.